# Interactive process with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, process, sh, interactive

I'm trying to interact with `sh`. This is the easiest case I want to resolve.

### The most easy is:

```kotlin
typealias ExitStatus = Int

fun executeIO(cmd: List<String>): ExitStatus =
    ProcessBuilder(cmd).inheritIO().start().waitFor()
```

But the Kotlin code doesn't have any control when the `sh` are executing.

### When you know how many times you want to write

```kotlin
fun executeNTimes(cmd: List<String>, times: Int) = runBlocking {
    val process = ProcessBuilder(cmd)
        .start()

    launch { process.errorStream.bufferedReader().useLines { seq -> seq.toList().forEach { println("stderr: $it") } } }
    launch { process.inputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { seq -> seq.toList().forEach { println("stdout: $it") } } }

    OutputStreamWriter(process.outputStream, "UTF-8").use { w ->
        repeat(times) {
            readln().let { println("input: $it"); w.write(it) }
            w.appendLine()
            w.flush()
        }
    }
    process.waitFor()
}
```

But that is not interactive!

> cmd = sh and times = 2:

```
echo exit on stdout
input: echo exit on stdout
echo exit on stderr 1>&2 
input: echo exit on stderr 1>&2
stderr: exit on stderr
stdout: exit on stdout
```

Is not interactive because needs to close the buffer for starting to work.

My expectation for interactive process is the next one:

```
input: echo exit on stdout
stdout: exit on stdout
input: echo exit on stderr 1>&2
stderr: exit on stderr
input: exit
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read:

- https://github.com/agavrilov76/ExpectIt

  - https://github.com/agavrilov76/ExpectIt/blob/master/expectit-core/src/test/java/net/sf/expectit/ProcessExample.java
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

The code has:

```kotlin
fun executeExpect() {
    val process = ProcessBuilder(listOf("sh")).start()
    val expect = ExpectBuilder()
        .withInputs(process.inputStream, process.errorStream)
        .withOutput(process.outputStream)
        .build()

    fun send(str: String) {
        expect.sendLine(str)
        println("input: $str")
    }
    "echo exit on stdout".let(::send)
    expect.expect(regexp("\n$")).before.let { println("stdout: $it") }
    "echo exit on stderr 1>&2".let(::send)
    expect.expectIn(1, regexp("\n$")).before.let { println("stderr: $it") }
    "exit".let(::send)
    expect.expect(eof());
    process.waitFor()
    expect.close()
}
```

And now the output is:

```
input: echo exit on stdout
stdout: exit on stdout
input: echo exit on stderr 1>&2
stderr: exit on stderr
input: exit
```